# Tomcat 7 acceptorThreadCount=2 - Anyone See Performance Gains?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

The documentation on Tomcat7 talks about acceptorThreadCount with an almost flippant remark of

> The number of threads to be used to accept connections. Increase this
>   value on a multi CPU machine, although you would never really need
>   more than 2

Are there any hard numbers, performance-wise, on setting this to 1 or 2?  Multi-core CPU's are the norm now, and I think you'd even have a hard time finding a single-core machine.  Should we always set this to 2 then?  Are performance gains note-worthy?

(Yes, I've tried running stress tests with this set to 1 and 2 and didn't notice any difference, which is why I'm asking if anyone else has different conclusions).